# Azure command line issue

Tags: azure

Hi I have following lines in the batch file ("StartupTasks.cmd") in our WebRole.

```
cacls d:\TestAccess /t /e /g Users:f
```

And in the ServiceDefinition.csdef file, I have,

```
<Startup>
      <Task commandLine="StartupTasks.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
      </Task>
</Startup>
```

While running the above command using command prompt, we are able to give fullcontrol to the folder TestAccess.

However while running using azure, I am unable to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had the same kind of issue, I added 
 this statement EXIT /B 0 before cacls d:\TestAccess /t /e /g Users:f

hence,
EXIT /B 0
cacls d:\TestAccess /t /e /g Users:f

should do.
I hope this helps

Comment: however cacls d:\TestAccess /t /e /g Users:f is in the next line